# Template name 'play-java' wasn't found in the template catalog

Tags: java, playframework, typesafe-activator

When I try to create a Play Java project, using [Activator](http://typesafe.com/activator), I get this error

```
new my-first-app play-java

Fetching the latest list of templates...

Template name 'play-java' wasn't found in the template catalog.
Try these template names: reactive-maps, reactive-stocks, hello-akka, hello-scala, hello-slick, hello-play
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `play-java-preview` - I think it hasn't been published as `play-java` yet pending the final play 2.3.0 release.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of templates that you can use.
To get an idea of the available templates you can use the **list-templates** command, i.e.

```
>./activator list-templates
```

One of the simplest Play Java templates is *hello-play-java*

HTH